# Swap on secured partition is not being mounting on boot

Tags: linux, boot, swap, luks

I've got a work laptop Lenovo P51. There is Win10 on a secured partition. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a secured partition as well. Also, I've created a secured partition for swap, but it doesn't mount.
The launch time is about 2 minutes what is very annoying

here is **sudo blkid** output and there is no a secured partition for swap (I supposed it should look like **/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p6**)

```
$ sudo blkid                                       
/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p7_crypt: UUID="94fe7730-b54e-43a6-be1c-ec4c1fcec084" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="BOOT" UUID="56A4-3F33" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="b2acdb69-298e-4720-8368-30a86df0d055"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: LABEL="DATA" UUID="160E3B620E3B3A57" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="e05129b9-f57e-48b3-8502-ad7129883615"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="95aa2c8c-2cd1-4fef-8dc3-c93a896e9f15" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="f12911aa-86cc-4d9a-8117-39fd5a31bd8e"
/dev/nvme0n1p7: UUID="20adda12-da97-4c79-af97-cb69a7a4af00" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="26e3155a-aee1-4185-82d2-a4d41d6cee6c"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="71954aea-d40f-480d-ad82-e574d4960a4d" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="db7c9553-7b2e-4b8d-acd4-b04a66af3bc2"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="cc57510d-4af0-4c72-9233-e2acf8b439d6"
/dev/nvme0n1p6: PARTUUID="00d5b8ac-276c-4662-acfc-16f9b3eaa098"
```

and **fstab** content:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
UUID=94fe7730-b54e-43a6-be1c-ec4c1fcec084 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=95aa2c8c-2cd1-4fef-8dc3-c93a896e9f15 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=56A4-3F33  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /media/DATA was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during installation
UUID=160E3B620E3B3A57 /media/DATA     ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
#/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p6_crypt none            swap    sw              0       0
```

UPD.
Uncommented last row in **fstab** (but it didn't fix anything)

```
$ sudo swapon -a              
swapon: cannot open /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p6_crypt: No such file or directory
```

Found this in **/var/log/syslog**

```
Aug 22 14:41:15 ThinkPad-P51 dockerd[1973]: time="2018-08-22T14:41:15.630102414+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit"
Aug 22 14:42:38 ThinkPad-P51 systemd[1]: dev-mapper-nvme0n1p6_crypt.swap: Job dev-mapper-nvme0n1p6_crypt.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

UPD2. **lsblk -f** output:

```
NAME                FSTYPE      LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0               squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-calculator/199
loop1               squashfs                                               /snap/canonical-livepatch/41
loop2               squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
loop3               squashfs                                               /snap/gimp/40
loop4               squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-logs/37
loop5               squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36
loop6               squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/59
loop7               squashfs                                               /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
loop8               squashfs                                               /snap/canonical-livepatch/42
loop9               squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-logs/25
loop10              squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-logs/40
loop11              squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-characters/103
loop12              squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-calculator/180
loop13              squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-characters/117
loop14              squashfs                                               /snap/core/4486
loop15              squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-system-monitor/54
loop16              squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-characters/69
loop17              squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-calculator/154
loop18              squashfs                                               /snap/core/5145
loop19              squashfs                                               /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
nvme0n1                                                                    
├─nvme0n1p1         vfat        BOOT  56A4-3F33                            /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2                                                                
├─nvme0n1p3                                                                
├─nvme0n1p4         ntfs        DATA  160E3B620E3B3A57                     /media/DATA
├─nvme0n1p5         ext4              95aa2c8c-2cd1-4fef-8dc3-c93a896e9f15 /boot
├─nvme0n1p6         swap              8c875a48-443f-4e04-9fd1-9a56b1da73cc [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p7         crypto_LUKS       20adda12-da97-4c79-af97-cb69a7a4af00 
  └─nvme0n1p7_crypt ext4              94fe7730-b54e-43a6-be1c-ec4c1fcec084 /
```

**UPD3. system-analyze blame output:**

```
6.228s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
3.782s apt-daily.service
3.459s plymouth-quit-wait.service
1.751s apt-daily-upgrade.service
1.343s docker.service
 847ms bolt.service
 770ms fwupd.service
 622ms snapd.service
 506ms systemd-logind.service
 496ms dev-mapper-nvme0n1p7_crypt.device
 471ms nvidia-fallback.service
 428ms snap-core-5145.mount
 427ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-70.mount
 407ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-154.mount
 399ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-54.mount
 398ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-69.mount
 384ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-117.mount
 379ms snap-core-4486.mount
 355ms snapd.seeded.service
 264ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-180.mount
 246ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-103.mount
 244ms dev-loop0.device
 231ms dev-loop3.device
 227ms dev-loop2.device
 218ms dev-loop1.device
 205ms dev-loop6.device
 204ms NetworkManager.service
 200ms dev-loop4.device
 189ms dev-loop8.device
 183ms dev-loop5.device
 181ms dev-loop9.device
 171ms dev-loop10.device
 160ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-40.mount
 156ms dev-loop7.device
 146ms systemd-timesyncd.service
 133ms snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-42.mount
 132ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-25.mount
 129ms networkd-dispatcher.service
 124ms systemd-resolved.service
 116ms udisks2.service
 110ms upower.service
 110ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-319.mount
 102ms systemd-journal-flush.service
  99ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
  94ms ModemManager.service
  80ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-36.mount
  80ms dev-loop11.device
  78ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-37.mount
  76ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-59.mount
  75ms accounts-daemon.service
  74ms dev-loop12.device
  72ms apparmor.service
  71ms keyboard-setup.service
  70ms apport.service
  66ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-51.mount
  58ms snap-gimp-40.mount
  56ms snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-41.mount
  47ms systemd-journald.service
  46ms thermald.service
  45ms speech-dispatcher.service
  45ms user@1000.service
  44ms user@120.service
  42ms packagekit.service
  42ms systemd-rfkill.service
  38ms alsa-restore.service
  37ms gpu-manager.service
  36ms avahi-daemon.service
  35ms grub-common.service
  35ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-56A4\x2d3F33.service
  32ms systemd-udevd.service
  29ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-199.mount
  25ms rsyslog.service
  24ms wpa_supplicant.service
  23ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-95aa2c8c\x2d2cd1\x2d4fef\x2d8dc3\x2dc93a896e9f15.service
  22ms pppd-dns.service
  22ms bluetooth.service
  21ms networking.service
  19ms media-DATA.mount
  16ms ureadahead-stop.service
  16ms gdm.service
  16ms systemd-modules-load.service
  14ms colord.service
  14ms plymouth-start.service
  13ms plymouth-read-write.service
  13ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
  12ms dns-clean.service
  12ms polkit.service
  12ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
  11ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
  10ms kmod-static-nodes.service
   9ms systemd-remount-fs.service
   9ms dev-hugepages.mount
   8ms docker.socket
   8ms kerneloops.service
   7ms boot.mount
   7ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
   7ms systemd-sysctl.service
   6ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
   6ms dev-mqueue.mount
   6ms dev-loop13.device
   6ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-8c875a48\x2d443f\x2d4e04\x2d9fd1\x2d9a56b1da73cc.swap
   6ms boot-efi.mount
   5ms ufw.service
   5ms systemd-update-utmp.service
   5ms dev-loop15.device
   4ms systemd-cryptsetup@nvme0n1p7_crypt.service
   4ms systemd-user-sessions.service
   4ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
   4ms console-setup.service
   4ms dev-loop18.device
   4ms systemd-backlight@leds:tpacpi::kbd_backlight.service
   3ms dev-loop19.device
   3ms systemd-random-seed.service
   3ms dev-loop16.device
   3ms dev-loop17.device
   3ms sys-kernel-config.mount
   2ms dev-loop14.device
   2ms rtkit-daemon.service
   2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
   2ms setvtrgb.service
   1ms snapd.socket
```

Comment: Is `/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p6` unlocked on boot? It needs to be unlocked before swap can be seen and mounted.

Comment: I don't know. How can I check it?

Comment: `lsblk -f` shows all accessible block devices in an easily readable tree graph. Please add the output of that to your question. If the encrypted containers are unlocked, then the contents will show up in that graph.

Comment: I've added the output of the command

Comment: According to the output, your swap partition is active (but not encrypted). Something else must be delaying the startup process. Do `systemd-analyze --blame` to see what could be causing it. If you have trouble with it, then post a new question about that issue.

Comment: In some way I connected it already, nevertheless, the computer still turns on about 2 minutes

Answer (score 1):

> Swap on secured partition is not being mounting on boot

But... the swap partition is commented in your `/etc/fstab`:

```
#/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p6_crypt none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Lines starting with `#` are not read.

Comment: Without # it not working as well. I've added this with a hope that disabling searching for swap will reduce loading time. Maybe Should I replace /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p6_crypt none with appropriate UUID but I don't know where to find it

Comment: Look what I found in /var/log/syslog:

    `Aug 22 14:41:15 ThinkPad-P51 dockerd[1973]: time="2018-08-22T14:41:15.630102414+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit"
    Aug 22 14:42:38 ThinkPad-P51 systemd[1]: dev-mapper-nvme0n1p6_crypt.swap: Job dev-mapper-nvme0n1p6_crypt.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'`

Maybe can this help?